# App Crashing due to animation in release mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have used animation in my app where I am changing height according to keyboard events. They are working fine in debug mode but app is crashing due to it in release or production mode build.

If I comment the animation code the release build working fine that assured me the problem is due to animation . I want to use animation and without removing code solve the problem.

This is my component I am rendering and using animation in it.

```
customFocusNavigator = () => {
return (
  <Animated.View
    style={[styles.FocusNavigator, { bottom: this.state.keyboardHeight }]}
  >
    <View style={styles.FocusNavigatorDirectionBox}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.state.index > 0
            ? this["customtext" + (this.state.index - 1)].changeFocus()
            : this["customtext0"].changeFocus();
        }}
        style={[
          styles.bottomSubView,
          { borderRightColor: constant.COLOR.WHITE, borderRightWidth: 1 }
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={styles.FocusNavigatorText}>Previous</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.state.index < 4
            ? this["customtext" + (this.state.index + 1)].changeFocus()
            : this["customtext0"].changeFocus();
        }}
        style={styles.bottomSubView}
      >
        <Text style={styles.FocusNavigatorText}>Next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}
    >
      <Text style={[styles.FocusNavigatorText, { fontWeight: "bold" }]}>
        Done
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Animated.View>
);
```

};

Following are the keyboard events where I changing animation.

```
_keyboardDidShow = e => {
(keyboardHeight = e.endCoordinates.height),
  Animated.timing(this.state.bottomPadding, {
    toValue: 0,
    duration: 150
  }).start();
Animated.timing(this.state.keyboardHeight, {
  toValue: Platform.OS === "ios" ? keyboardHeight : 0,
  duration: 150
}).start();
this.setState({ isFocused: true });
}

_keyboardDidHide = () => {
Animated.timing(this.state.bottomPadding, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 150
}).start();
Animated.timing(this.state.keyboardHeight, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 0
}).start();
this.setState({ isFocused: false });
}
```

And rest is value in state:

```
keyboardHeight: new Animated.Value(0),
```

I still unable to found the exact reason for crashing . Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The animation looks fine, I had a similar problem with directly controlling the height of a view because it's not performant. I would use `transform` instead.

Your `View` style should look like this:

```
style={
   [ 
     styles.FocusNavigator, 
     { 
       transform: 
        [
           { translateY: this.state.keyboardHeight * -1 }
        ]
     }
   ]
}
```

without `* -1` it moves the view downwards.

If you need to change the height of the view you could add a scale property to the transformation.

Comment: Okay.. So no need to use animation ? If I use transform . Will it change with jerk or smoothly like animation because thats the main reason for using animation

Comment: Leave everything as it is just replace the style object with the code I've written, you are still using your animation function this way.

Comment: for better performance you could add this: Animated.timing(this.state.bottomPadding, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 150, useNativeDriver: Platform.OS === "android"
}).start();

Comment: App is still crashing in release mode